# GraphSlam Doubt

Tags: algorithms, graphs, sparse-matrices

I am trying to implement Graph slam. I have some doubts regrading implementation. I attached a picture to clarify my doubt.

[[image]

[image]

I have a doubt in line number 2. It show omega have a scalar value 0. But at line 3 it show omega is a Matrix.

Next doubt at line 7. In this line omega which is a 3*3 matrix is add with a 6*6 matrix. As per my knowledge it is impossible.

I share the link of the paper where page no: 411-412 define this algorithm. Link of the paper is http://robots.stanford.edu/papers/thrun.graphslam.pdf.

If any one working on it please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Often we use $0$ to represent the all-zeros matrix, so the instruction to set $\Omega = 0$ might mean to set it to the all-zeros matrix (with a zero in every entry).  You'll have to figure out from context whether that seems correct.

Comment: That is not return anywhere that omega has a scalar value zero or it is a 3*3 matrix.